I have received the below error below link error while i test the docker file on base machine with docker desktop support
Receiving link file issues: Testing on windows host but checking linux files path. How to sort out this?
This is my dockerfile
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM --platform=windows/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
WORKDIR /install

Build output:
------
 > [1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022@sha256:0ae307b6ad9ff16ecf2ea15da2ba0f60f6163281193241b9cc308fbc05f01e9d:
------
DPS.Build.DockerFile:4
--------------------
   2 |
   3 |     # https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
   4 | >>> FROM --platform=windows/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
   5 |     WORKDIR /install
   6 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to register layer: link /Files/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/System/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui: no such file or directory

I want the image to build successfully on my host. Windows version 2022.
